# What files do pppoeconf modify?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, networking

For a setup I'm putting on I was able to make a working config with pppoeconf however I would like to understand what files `pppoeconf` modify in order to configure them manually without that command next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the files modified are this ones:

> **/etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider** is pppd options file for your dsl
>   provider.
>
> **/etc/ppp/pap-secrets** and **/etc/ppp/chap-secrets** are described in pppd
>   documentation. pppoeconf may add lines to theses files.
>
> **/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/0clampmss** and **/etc/ppp/ip-down.d/0clampmss** are used
>   to clamp MSS if needed.
>
> **/etc/network/interfaces** is network interface file for your system.

What I miss is if `pppoeconf` also add some entries to scripts at boot time so that pppoe is loaded properly.